# About the usage of whether to.....or not

Tags: whether

I would like to know whether the following three sentences are grammatically correct or acceptable.

1. Whether to kill him or to keep him is up to you.
2. I have to decide whether to kill him or to keep him.
3. Whether to kill him or to keep him, we have to beware of the consequence.

Answer (score 3):

I believe all are correct but perhaps a bit stilted, or less than comfortable.

It would be more natural to say *Whether to kill him or keep him*. The missing *to* would certainly be understood. This would be common for spoken English or written as a quote from someone. Perhaps you should ask him. He may have a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

*Whether to kill him or to keep him* is a phrase that functions as a subject in 1 and an object in 2.

Whether to eliminate the second *to* in the phrase is a matter of style.

But 3 is incorrect.  The phrase is unattached to anything; it would be grammatical if it were changed to *whether we kill him or keep him.”*

Comment: Thank you both for replying. I would like to add another sentence: Whether he trusted me, or whether he pitied me, I will do what he told me to do.

Comment: That one is fine, although the first comma is unnecessary.

Comment: I wouldn't go along with you there. "Whether to kill him or to keep him" is not a phrase but a subordinate interrogative infinitival clause. In 2. for example, it's not an object, but complement of "decide". The meaning can be glossed as  "I have to decide whether I should kill him or keep him".

Comment: @billjnThank you for this correction. I’ll delete whenever there’s another answer that doesn’t identify 3 as correct.

Comment: @BillJ What do you think about sentence 3?